# volume of intersection of a plane and a sphere

Tags: volume, spheres, multiple-integral

given a,b,c,d in R.
what's the volume of:
$ax+by+cz<d; x^2+y^2+z^2<1$.
I've tried using polar coordinates, but got a really hard integral. Is there a way to solve it with integrals?

Comment: Maybe a coordinate change so the plane becomes $z_1=k$ would be useful.

Comment: Once you've changed the coordinates, it's easy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

Comment: I thought about it, but then all the mess moves to the sphere.

Comment: Nnnnnno, suppose you change the coordinates when all the distances remain the same, the oriented distance between $(0,0,0)$ and $ax+by+cz-d=0$ is $-\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$ then the latter expression $=-k$

Comment: if you will write a full answer(not in the comments). you will get: my full gratitude. an up vote of mine. if I believe it's right, the v of correct answer. thanks!

Comment: Please write and show the triple integral here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried to solve it. hope someone will review it.
[image: A solution?]